# Have any scripts been developed for migrating GiftWorks to CiviCRM

Tags: migration

Apparently GiftWorks has been bought by Frontstream and we have had our first enquiry from someone wanting to explore shifting to CiviCRM. They have been told their old system will be shut down in July 2019. They have the option of being migrated to Frontstream but want to consider other options.

I can't find any public references yet to any migration scripts for this.

Comment: If anyone publishes their migration scripts besides me, I'm unaware of it - and I don't have a GiftWorks migration script.

Comment: perhaps there is a place in documentation where this could be more clearly an option. totally appreciate the openness you have taken to you migration work. was unclear what happened with the project we helped on getting client off NB but i should query the other Partners who did that side of things